# getting redirected to root when having a special character in request - laravel 5

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

here's my routes file:

```
Route::any('target',function(){
    return 'got it!';
});
```

here's my form:

```
<form method='post' action='example.com/target'>
    <input type='text' name='message' />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>
```

so It doesn't matter what I fill as the `message` field , It should return me `got it!`
but when I enter a `url` in `message` field , no matter the method is POST or GET , whether the path exist's or not, I get redirected to the root (`example.com`)
I don't have this problem on localhost, but on the shared host
thanks

Comment: _“I don't have this problem on localhost, but on the shared host”_ – then it is probably some sort of “security feature”, that blocks/redirects requests containing certain content. Suggest you talk to the server admin.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `APP_URL` env variable in `config/app.php`

Make sure once you are in production (or any other env for that matter), this value is changed accordingly.

---

edit:

Also check your action, either use named routes and route('route-name') or the url helpers to get proper urls.

Url helpers:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ Url::to('/target') }}">
```

Named routes:

```
 Route::any('target', function(){
     return 'got it!';
 })->name('target-name');
```

With your form action like this:

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ route('target-name') }}">
```

Also, is that the only route you have specified? Or are there more routes defined where you use target ?

Comment: there are other routes , but they have nothing to do with this one, as I said , It doesn't even matter If the route exist's or not, sending the url of this page to a path like (example.com/asdf) which doesn't exist will redirect me to (example.com) but If Instead of url I would just send a simple text , then It would cause 404 error

Comment: You should not put the example.com part in the action, just the relative path to the route. The helper method will help you do that.

Comment: I did this `action="{{url('/target')}}"` so It output's example.com/target and nothing's changed, you're going a totally wrong way I guess, It's not about wrong address

Comment: Then you should probably contact the server admin... Perhaps /target is reserved for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

change your action into this `action='/target'`

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code in 2 ways.

First of all change the route like this

```
Route::get('/target', array('as'=>'target_name','uses'=>function(){
       return 'got it!';
}));
```

After that you can use like this way

1) `<form method="post" action="{{ URL::to('/target') }}">`

or

2) `<form method="post" action="{{ URL::route('target_name') }}">`

Thanks